# Typescript Generic and Non-Generic Version of Type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a very short question, I'm trying to make two classes in typescript:

```
export class ServiceResponse { }

export class ServiceResponse<T> extends ServiceResponse {}
```

but according to typescript, these are duplicate identifiers.  Is it possible to use the same name with a generic type argument in typescript?  Is this a problem that someone has solved before?  I come from a `C#` background, where this pattern is fairly common.

Thanks!

Comment: No, but you have default generic parameters, which might help: `class ServiceResponse<T = void>{}`

Comment: @AlekseyL That's great! Thanks, I didn't think to see if there was a possible default value on a generic

Comment: You're welcome! Another possible solution would be splitting the code into 2 files and "aliasing" non generic base class with some other name on import: `import { ServiceResponse as _ServiceResponse } from './ServiceResponse.ts';`

Answer (score 7):

*Aleksey answered the question in the comment above, but just wanted to provide an actual answer with more context for future reference*

This is expected since the Typescript type annotations (including the generic type parameter `<T>` here) are stripped out when compiled down to JavaScript, and you end up with two classes with the same name, hence the **duplicate identifier** error.

In order to define a generic and non-generic versions of the same class, you can specify a default value for your generic type parameter:

```js
export class ServiceResponse<T = void> {
}
```